# SVC client proxy and WSDL hosted on remote server

Tags: wcf, wsdl, iis-6, wcf-client, svc

I have one wsdl and xsd then I generated a SVC client proxy from a wsdl, wsdl is hosted on  windows server 2003 (outside local domain), somewhere on internet. XSD is also located at same place. I can see them in web browser, no issue there.

Then I made a simple console application client, when I run the client, I see in fiddler that correct soap response is there but in console application response is null, i.e. SVC client can not deserialize  it.

I am sure that xsd + wsdl are correct and response too(I see in fiddler).

When I put wsdl and xsd's on local domain server(intranet), it's all good, I see response in application properly deserialized.

If I compare both situation in fiddler, I don't see any difference in raw response.

Few more points: I am not hosting WCF service in IIS. I have got a different service running remotely. Let me know if I clarify more things.

Thank you.

Edit/ Update:Cleaned post. Problem seems not to be IIS6 or IIS7, it's remote server creating trouble with schema location. In SVC proxy client MessagContract namespace if pointed to a outside server, problem occurs else on intranet server it runs just fine.

Example:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped = false)]
public partial class responseTypeOfMethod1
{

[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute( Namespace = "http://testserver.xxxxx/yyyy.wsdl", Order = 0)]
public RAT_type RAT;
................
....
..

}
```

if http://testserver.xxxxx points to local server, all fine, if points to an internet server , response is null

Comment: Anybody,ever seen such a glitch? I am out of ideas.namspace url,local server works,outside server don't.

Comment: Can you try to generate a proxy and use that in the client and see if the deserialization works without any problem. Make sure to remove your service reference that you have added.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things that could be happening here:

1. The response is not being returned from the remote server
2. The client is not able to deserialize the response

Use wireshark or some other network sniffer to see what response in coming back.

If the problem is due to inability to deserialize, it is probably a difference in the namespace.

Comment: Thank you Shiraz for your reply, I checked that in fiddler, response is there, also in SVC log and it's correct response. It's a deserialization issue but only when wsdl is on outside our local domain. Something is wrong with schema location, when it's on remove server. When I point namespace to local server, all fine. I am cleaning the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It was namespace problem of-course, took a long time to find out a nasty place in server code, a tool we use internally. Thank you all who replied for your time.